# How can I make this RewriteRule redirect to the right page?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, url-routing

First of all I hope I'll be clear enough and you can help me.

There's something I really don't understand, I've been trying to figure it out for hours, but in vain.
Here's the thing:

When I type `domainname/profile`, I want to be redirected to `domainname/index.php?url=profile` but instead, I'm redirected to `domainname/index.php?url=index.php`.

In my Rooter.php file, I did a `var_dump($_GET)` and it shows `'url' => 'index.php'`, that's how I know it.

Here's my Rooter.php:

```php
<?php 

require_once('views/View.php');

class Router {

    private $_controller;
    private $_view;

    public function route() {
        try {
            // Load classes automatically
            spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
               require_once('models/'.$class.'.php'); 
            });

            $url = [];

            if(isset($_GET['url']) && $_GET['url'] != '') {
                $url = explode('/', filter_var($_GET['url'], FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
                $controllerName = ucfirst(strtolower($url[0]));
                $controllerClass = "Controller".$controllerName;
                $controllerFile = 'controllers/'.$controllerClass.'.php';

                var_dump($_GET); die;

                if(file_exists($controllerFile)) {
                    require_once($controllerFile);
                    $this->_controller = new $controllerClass($url);
                } else {
                    throw new Exception('Page introuvable');
                }
            } else {
                require_once('controllers/ControllerHome.php');
                $this->_controller = new ControllerHome($url);
            }
        } catch(Exception $e) {
             $errorMsg = $e->getMessage();
             $this->_view = new View('Error');
             $this->_view->generate(['errorMsg' => $errorMsg]);
        }

    }

}

?>
```

Here's my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1
```

The weird thing is, when I replace `(.*)` by `[a-ZA-Z0-9]+`, IT WORKS, I'm redirected to the page domainname/index.php?url=profile and my `var_dump($_GET)` shows `'url' => 'profile'`.

What's wrong ? I wanted to use `(.*)` because it allows me to use severals slashes in my URLs, I can "fix" it by putting several RewriteRules for example `RewriteRule ^[a-zA-Z0-9]+/[a-zA-Z0-9]+$ index.php?url=$1` but in my opinion it's a weird way to make it work, it's not fully dynamical...

Anyway I hope you will understand my issue. Thanks in advance!

Btw: I work in my localhost but I have the same issue on my distant server.

Comment: `Options FollowSymLinks` `RewriteEngine On` `RewriteBase /` `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand that the rewriting engine makes multiple runs, so restarts the rewriting process if the request has been rewritten, unless you told it not to. That means you need to slightly change your setup to solve this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.\.php$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1 [END]
```

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a distributed configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a distributed configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using distributed configuration files (".htaccess"). Those distributed configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).